# Algolia Hacker News search api #browse endpoint

Tags: algolia, hacker-news-api

It seems that the Algolia Hacker News search API is limited to returning 1000 records:

hn.algolia.com/api

Algolia provides a #browse endpoint that can be used to gather all search results.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#browse-all-index-content

https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/index-configuration/how-can-i-retrieve-all-the-records-in-my-index

Does anyone know if this endpoint is exposed at hn.algolia.com/api/v1/ without requiring an api key and Algolia app ID, and what the index names (for example for stories and comments) are?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using [HackerNewsDownloader](https://github.com/sytelus/HackerNewsDownloader) -> it simulates a browse iterating over all entries using the "created_at" criteria.